# convert string (calculation )to number

Tags: jquery, string, parsefloat

I need convert `okString[1]` value to number, there is calculation for ex. 6.2*2.
[I tried](http://api.jquery.com/Types/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Types&redirect=no#Built-in_Methods) JQUERY API Doc`

"Or you use the String class provided by javascript, which try to parse a value as string:

String( 1 ) + String( 2 ); // "12"
String( 1 + 2 ); // "3" "

My code is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lostika86/fUgwr/)
`

```
 <div id="userForm">

<input id="string_input" value="1=2,6;2=4,5;3=5;5=6.1;7=6,2*2">

<!-- end -->
</div>​


$('#string_input').click(function() {
    fnWorkMainString();


});


function fnWorkMainString() {
    fnWorkSubString();

}

function fnWorkSubString() {
    var getString = $('#string_input').val();



   var divString = getString.split(';');
    console.log('divString ' + divString.length);
    var stringAfterDiv = [];
    var okString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < divString.length; i++) {
        console.log(divString[i]);
        stringAfterDiv[i] = divString[i].split('=');
        console.log(stringAfterDiv[i]);

        okString= stringAfterDiv[i][1].replace(',','.');    
          console.log(String(okString));
    }
    console.log(String( 1 + 2 ));

    return stringAfterDiv;
}​
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for

Comment: for example from 6,2*2 I need 12.4, or 5.3+5 => 10.3 atc

Comment: It works just fine when I try alert(String(6.2 * 2)). Try just using a string replacement to change comma's to periods, and it's fine.

Comment: @Joost But I dont use static string. alert(String(okString)); doesnt work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a go with the eval function.. This turned out to work (returned 22.2). I'm simply prepending an assignment to the calculation string (after replacing commas with dots)

```
var str = "2*7.1 + 4/0,5";
str = str.replace(',','.');
eval("var answer = "+str);
alert(answer);
```

or in a nifty function, skipping the assignment altogether

```
function computeString(str) {
   return eval(str.replace(',','.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
parseFloat("3",10)

OR

parseInt("3",10)
```

Comment: But 6,2*2 => 6.2 not 12.4 with parseInt(okString,10)

Comment: Or you use the String class provided by javascript, which try to parse a value as string:

String( 1 ) + String( 2 ); // "12"
String( 1 + 2 ); // "3" .. I tried String() too..

Comment: Then you need to again split the string based on the operators and only then do the math

Comment: And what is the number before = ??   7=6,2*2

Comment: / before = the numbers will be IDs